# How Oracle detects transaction deadlocks?

Tags: oracle, deadlock

What algorithm oracle used to detect deadlocks? What are the steps involved in deadlock detection? I would appreciate if someone explain it step by step. Thanks.

Comment: There's a reasonably complete explanation here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17275_01/html/programmer_reference/lock_dead.html

Comment: @RobertHarvey - That documentation appears to be for Berkeley DB, another database product owned by Oracle Corp, not for the Oracle database owned by Oracle Corp...  Confusing that they're both under docs.oracle.com.

Comment: Sheesh.  Well, in any case, the interwebz say that most deadlocks in Oracle are caused by unindexed foreign keys, FWIW.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - I already visited that page but I was confused that it was about barkley DB.

Comment: Yeah, already got that, but thanks for saying it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At a high level, when session A requests a lock, Oracle either gives it or it records that session A is blocked by whatever session holds whatever lock it is interested in acquiring, session B.  In the simplest case, if A is blocked on B while B is simultaneously blocked on A, you have a deadlock.  More generally, when there is any sort of cycle in the dependency graph-- A is blocked on B, B is blocked on C, C is blocked on A-- then you have a deadlock.  To detect deadlocks, Oracle merely has to periodically (every few seconds) traverse this dependency graph, note any cycles, and resolve the deadlock by terminating one of the requests with an ORA-00060 error.

Of course, you can get pretty deep into the weeds of why deadlocks occur, how to prevent them, how Oracle determines what session is holding the lock, etc. but that could get pretty involved unless you want to narrow the question a bit.

Comment: Would Oracle do that periodically, or when someone requests a lock that is not readily available? That would also make it deterministic which of the requests will be cancelled (the late-comer).

Comment: @Thilo - I believe it is done periodically because it is something that the PMON process does in the background, not something that is part of the general-case lock request code.  Otherwise, you'd potentially have hundreds of blocked sessions looking for cycles in the dependency graph.

Comment: I read somewhere that Oracle solves the lock-graph for deadlocks every 3 seconds.  If a cycle is found, the transaction which has done the least amount of work is rolled back.  If a tie, one is picked arbitrarily.